# Best way to embed a google map using web2py

Tags: google-maps, web2py

What's the best way to show a map (google maps or otherwise) with web2py.  Ideally, I have a pair of lat/longs or zip codes and I'd like to show the route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[plugin_wiki](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/12#plugin_wiki) includes a Google Maps widget (see the list of [widgets](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/12#Current-widgets) for details), which can be used independent of wiki pages. Otherwise, you can use the usual methods for including maps in web pages (which don't depend on anything special happening within web2py) -- for example, see the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/).